# Can ESP point to a global variable

Tags: x86, stack, shellcode

This 3 lines of code are used by some encoders to get EIP into ECX register:

```
fldz
fnstenv [esp-C]
pop ecx
```

The 2 first instructions push some datas on stack and we get one of this into ECX on the last line.

I have tried this code in a very basic poc. It works fine.

But in real life (in a Buffer overflow application), ecx contains 0x0000000 and I do not understand why.

The only thing I know is ESP value has been changed, but points in the middle of a big buffer.

Are there some rules on ESP ? Can ESP points anywhere (on an allocated memory region of course) ?

For example if I create a global variable in my program: unsigned char buf[1024]. Can I set ESP to buf+512 and call PUSH, fldz or fnstenv instructions ?

Thanks

Comment: You might require fninit before the fldz, to initialise the FPU state explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

**ESP always points to the top of stack.** Do you really understand stack concept? If you overwrite esp with random value, the application can crash.

**fldz** - Push +0.0 onto the **FPU** stack.
**fnstenv** - Store **FPU** environment in the area which is placed on memory in your case. **[esp-C]** - this is memory pointer.
**pop ecx** - just pop dword from the top of stack to the ecx

What do you want to do with this code? Describe your task.

Comment: I know what is stack and how it works. The os creates a memory space for the stack. My question is will it work if i put an esp value that points on another memory space. I am not talking about a random memory space. I am talking about a buffer i control. I want to know if the cpu will detect this is not the memory space dedicated for stack

Comment: You can change ESP, but after that pop/return instruction will work incorrect and call/push will store ret_addr/value outside the stack, because you change stack pointer(a location where data was stored). You can use ESP as general purpose register.